# SQL queries, I need to get some values

Tags: php, mysql

I got 2 tables, table1 & table2.

table1 have fields:

```
id
atype
adesc
aid
```

table2 have fields:

```
id
aid
adesc
value_1
value_2
```

```
$query1 = mysql_query("Select DISTINCT atype from table1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
    $atype = $row['atype'];
    $query2 = mysql_query("Select adesc from table1 where atype='$atype' and aid IN (Select aid from table2 ) order by id asc");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        // i know query2 can only get adesc, so i need value_1 and value_2 in this
        echo $row2['adesc'] .'>> '. (this should be value1 from table2) .'>> '. (this should be value2 from table2);
    }
}
```

I want to get the `value_1` and `value_2` too. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
table1 values are in my database (atype, aid, adesc respectively):

```
type1 111 'this is type 1'
type1 111 'this is type 1'
type2 112 'this is type 2'
type3 113 'this is type 3'
type4 114 'this is type 4'
type1 111 'this is type 1'
type4 114 'this is type 4'
type2 112 'this is type 2'
```

values on my table2 (aid,adesc,val1,val2, respectively):

```
111  'this is type 1' 100 50
111  'this is type 1' 100 50
112  'this is type 2' 300 500
113  'this is type 3' 100 50
112  'this is type 2' 100 50
114  'this is type 4' 100 50
111  'this is type 1' 100 50
```

what i really want to project is this:

```
type1
      (sum)value_1 (sum)value_2
type2 
      (sum)value_1 (sum)value_2
type3
      (sum)value_1 (sum)value_2
type4
      (sum)value_1 (sum)value_2
```

Comment: I really hope `$atype` is never `"Jade's Type"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $query2 = mysql_query("Select t1.adesc, t2.value_1, t2.value_2 from table1 as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.atype='$atype' and t1.aid = t2.aid order by t1.id asc");

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        // i know query2 can only get adesc, so i need value_1 and value_2 in this
        echo $row2['adesc'] .'>> '. $row2['value_1'] .'>> '. $row2['value_2'];
    }
```

upd:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
select t1.adesc, sum(t2.value_1) as v1, sum(t2.value_2)  as v2
from 
table1 as t1,
table2 as t2

where 
t1.aid = t2.aid 
group by t1.atype

order by t1.atype asc
SQL;
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
    // i know query2 can only get adesc, so i need value_1 and value_2 in this
        echo $row['adesc'] .'>> '. $row['v1']  .'>> '. $row['v2'];
}
```

Comment: apparently they're not working on how i should dispay it. please check my edit info for details.

Comment: thx for your update mate, im now 1 less worry free :D thx a lot.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use one simple innerjoin in SQL, instead of your two selects:

```
select table1.adesc,atable2.value1 from table1,table2 where table2.adesc=table1.adesc and table1.aid=table2.aid order by table1.aid asc
```

Edit:

```
select table1.adesc,atable2.value1 from table1,table2 where table1.aid=table2.aid order by table1.aid asc
```

Comment: That's it - Connor wrote the whole code based on an innerjoin.

Comment: "table2.adesc=table1.adesc" This condition was not specified in the source code

Comment: @int2000 apparently they're not working on how i should dispay it. please check my edit info for details.

Answer (score -1):

This SQL query should produce the results you want:

```
select adesc, 
       value_1, 
       value_2 

from   table1 

where  atype='$atype' and 
       aid IN (Select aid from table2 ) 

order by id asc
```